# Image link show well on Laptop, but it not found in Android Phone and iOS Phone

Tags: android, html, iphone, image, web

I have a image link in my website here
Link:
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-qn5ZhWnVvWQ/T6SoBT14ZEI/AAAAAAAAE30/lBE7TZsIW4M/s0/HKGH-BLOGTRUYEN.COM-Vol16-Chap104-P00.jpg

When i show it in a Laptop , it shows well. But when i try to click that link in my Android (and other Android ), other iOS (iPhone, bla bla ). The image not found!
What is wrong with that link there and how to solve that?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iTUv.png

Your link has nothing wrong. Are you sure you've clicked on the correct link when trying on a mobile device?
Please retry.